# Do Dota 2 battle point boosters stack?

Tags: dota-2

I have this battle point booster that is **80%** already activated ,but I want to buy the **400%** one to activate it at the same time.

Do they stack?

Answer (score 1):

They don't stack for the same player. However, your 400% would give benefits to the other players and that'd stack with their existing bonus.